# Как сделать изменяющуюся(динамичную/анимированную) иконку приложения Android?

Tags: java, android

У некоторых системных приложений вроде Календаря и Часов имеются динамично меняющиеся иконки. У календаря на иконке отображается число текущего дня, а у часов на иконке каждые 5 минут обновляется состояние стрелок, показывающих время. Можно ли как-то реализовать такую иконку в своем приложении?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не совсем иконки, а виджеты приложений. API создания виджетов известно и открыто.

[Ссылка на официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets)

Краткий [туториал здесь](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html)

Касательно комментария @Style-7 - он ссылается на инструкцию (сильно устаревшую) по созданию shortcut'а (ссылки) на приложение в Home Screen.